# Using dependency injection correctly with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS for the first time and I have the following files, which I created myself.

**Demo.html**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./modules.js"></script>
        <script src="./product.js"></script>
        <title>Your Shopping Cart</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: arial;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid darkgray;
        }
        tr {
            background-color: slategray;
            color: white;
        }
        td {
            padding: 15px;
        }
        .outofstock {
            color: red;
        }
        .instock {
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
    <body ng-controller="CartController">
        <h1>Your Order</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            <span ng-bind="item.title"></span>
            <input ng-model="item.quantity" />
            <span ng-class="{instock: isInStock($index), outofstock: !isInStock($index)}" ng-bind="stockCheck($index)"></span>
            <span ng-bind="item.price | currency"></span>
            <span ng-bind="calculateCost(item.price, item.quantity) | currency"></span>
            <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <table class="totals">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Nett Total: </b><span ng-bind="bill.totalCart | currency"></span></td>
                <td><b>Discount: </b><span ng-bind="bill.discount | currency"></span></td>
                <td><b>Sales Tax: </b><span ng-bind="bill.salesTax | currency"></span></td>
                <td><b>Gross Total: </b><span ng-bind="bill.subTotal | currency"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>

        myApp.controller('CartController', [
            '$scope', 'appProduct', 
            function($scope,product) {
            $scope.salesTaxPercent = 20;

            $scope.bill = {};

            $scope.items = product.getProducts();

                $scope.remove = function(index) {
                    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
                }

                $scope.stockCheck = function(index) {
                    if (isNaN($scope.items[index].quantity))
                        return 'Invalid quantity';

                    if ($scope.isInStock(index))
                        return ($scope.items[index].stock - $scope.items[index].quantity) + ' left in stock';
                    else
                        return 'Out of stock';                      
                }

                $scope.isInStock = function(index) {
                    var result = true;
                    if ($scope.items[index].quantity >= $scope.items[index].stock)
                        result = false;

                    return result;
                }

                $scope.calculateCost = function(price, qty) {
                    return price * qty;
                }

                var calculateTotals = function() {
                    var total = 0;
                    $scope.items.forEach(function(item) {
                        if (!isNaN(item.quantity))
                            total = total + $scope.calculateCost(item.price, item.quantity);
                    });
                    $scope.bill.totalCart = total;
                    $scope.bill.discount = total > 100 ? 10 : 0;
                    $scope.bill.salesTax = total * $scope.salesTaxPercent / 100
                    $scope.bill.subTotal = total - $scope.bill.discount + $scope.bill.salesTax;
                };

                $scope.$watch('items', calculateTotals, true);
            }
        ]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**modules.js**

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

**products.js**

```
'use strict';

myApp.factory('appProduct', ['$q',
    function($q) {
        var $this = function() {
            angular.extend(this, {
                getProducts : getProducts
            });
        };

        function getProducts() {
            return {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95, stock: 10},
                    {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95, stock: 20},
                    {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95, stock: 10};
        };
    }
]);
```

When I run the Demo.html file I am not getting the 3 products I've mocked in the `getProducts` method.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your getProducts object array should be wrapped in []

Comment: I don't understand why my question has been down voted considering I don't know anything about AngularJS and came on here to get some help. I would appreciate any comments as to the reasons for down voting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to figure out what the issue was -- it was caused by an erroneous semi-colon added to the  'Pebbles' array element in `getProducts`.  After removing the semi-colon the application works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors in the console when running this? Try setting a breakpoint on the `$scope.items = product.getProducts();` and inspect what the value of product is.

Is your file really named **products**.js (emphasis on the trailing S)? I notice that your `<script>` tag includes `src="./product.js"` which if true will not be found.

-- Update --

Added a JSFiddle of the code you provided http://jsfiddle.net/v30njcfu/1/

As you can see in your console the error is

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

This will be due to attempting to use myApp before it is defined. Check your network tab of your browser's developer tools to check that module.js really has been loaded.

Also, your appProduct factory is creating a variable `$this` which extends `this` by adding the getProducts() function, but this does not actually change the definition of this so it should be simplified to `this.getProducts = function() { ... }` as in the fiddle or at least `return $this`.

Comment: Just checked the console and there is an `[$injector:unpr]` error in there.  Looks like it cannot inject `appProduct` for some reason.